# jQuery add text to span when div is visible

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="box">
<span class="test"></span>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="button">

<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        display: none;
     }
</style>
```

above div is not visible when page is load. We are making div visible after button click. Now i want to append text to span when div is visible.

```
$('#button').on("click",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.box').clone().show().append('.row');
});
```

I tried this

```
1) $(".box").closest(".test").text("hello");
2) $(".box").find(".test").text("hello");
```

But it is not adding text into span.

Comment: Try `$(".box").find(".test").text("hello");`

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla not working using find.

Comment: Whats the objective of using `.clone()`?

Comment: .clone() method create clone of specified class and insert into div.

Comment: @rajesh: but you have not appended the cloned element somewhere.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar i updated my question.

Comment: wrong syntax for appending element. http://jsfiddle.net/6j014eb4/

Answer (score 2):

`.closest` traverses through parent elements. You need to use `.find()` instead of `.closest()` selector to search child elements:

```
 $(".box .test").text("hello");
```

or

```
 $(".box").find(".test").text("hello");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6j014eb4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to use `find()` with select `visible` instead of `closest()`.

`closest()` looks for the element with a given class in the parents of selector while find looks at the children of the selector

```
$(".box:visible").find(".test").text("hello");
```

The this is, it is not adding because your find statement gets executed before your div is made visible. You need to execute your adding text statement after you div has been made visible and it will work as shown in snippet below

```js
$(function(){
      $('#toggle').click(function(){
       console.log('click');
        $('.box').css("display", "block");
        $('.box').find('.test').text("Hello");
      })
      
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="box">
    
    <span class="test"></span>
    
    </div>
    <button id="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("button").on("click",function(){

         $(".box").find(".test").text("hello");

         $(".box").show(500);

     })

 })
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            display: none;
         }
    </style>
    
</head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="box">
            <span class="test"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        
        <button>SHOW DIV</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function(){

             $("button").on("click",function(){

                 $(".box").find(".test").text("hello");

                 $(".box").show(500);

             })

         })
 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)/[Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to target the `test` element.

Additionally, you need to use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) instead of [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> The `.append()` and `.appendTo()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".box:first")
    .clone()
    .find(".test")
    .text("hello")
    .end()
    .show()
    .appendTo('.row');
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <span class="test"></span>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```